# Recursive definition of nested sums

Tags: functions, recursion

I have a set of functions which take lists as arguments. They recursively nest sums, and I have defined them as follows

```
s0[x_, y_] := Total[x] - Total[y]
s1[x_, y_] := 
 Sum[x[[i]] (s0[x[[i + 1 ;; Length[x]]], y]), {i, Length[x]}] - 
  Sum[y[[i]] (s0[{}, y[[i ;; Length[y]]]]), {i, Length[y]}]
s2[x_, y_] := 
 Sum[x[[i]] (s1[x[[i + 1 ;; Length[x]]], y]), {i, Length[x]}] - 
  Sum[y[[i]] (s1[{}, y[[i ;; Length[y]]]]), {i, Length[y]}]
```

I wish to create a general function Sn which takes the lists x and y as arguments and a third argument n which determines how many times to nest. However when I try the obvious

```
Sn[n_,x_,y_]:=Sum[x[[i]] (Sn[n-1,x[[i + 1 ;; Length[x]]], y]), {i, Length[x]}] - 
  Sum[y[[i]] (Sn[n-1,{}, y[[i ;; Length[y]]]]), {i, Length[y]}]
```

The function does not evaluate (it just keeps running). I have tried including a term like

```
Sn[0,x_,y_]:=s0[x,y]
```

but this does not seem to have helped matters.

Comment: Stackexchange etiquette: If your problem is solved, you should consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it right!

```
sn[n_, x_, y_] := 
   Sum[x[[i]] (sn[n - 1, x[[i + 1 ;; Length[x]]], y]), {i, Length[x]}] - 
    Sum[y[[i]] (sn[n - 1, {}, y[[i ;; Length[y]]]]), {i, Length[y]}];
sn[0, x_, y_] := Total[x] - Total[y]
```

So for example:

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10];
sn[4, x, y]
```